# Why is my Material UI Table Hidden after "Show" toggle

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using the [Grow](https://mui.com/components/transitions/) material ui component to show/hide a table. By default I see the table.
[image]

```
  <Box className={classes.object_controls_wrapper}>
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Grow in={objectViewOpened}>{object_controls_view}</Grow>
    </Box>
    <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
              checked={objectViewOpened}
              onChange={handleToggleObjectViewOpened}
          />
        }
        label="Show"
    />
  </Box>
```

However after I toggle the show button the table is hidden behind the map.

[image]

The parent div still is at a large z-index.
[image]

If I use the icon in the material UI example.. its visibility toggles properly and is not hidden in this fashion.

What suggestions do you have relative to finding the CSS attribute that is causing this to be hidden?

---

**CODE SANDBOX LINKS**

Per suggestion.. [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-snowflake-4ej8d) is my codesandbox with the triangle.. show toggle in upper-right.. it works as expected

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/growworkswithtable-ismt7) is the version with material-table.. it doesnt work.

---

**FURTHER INPUT**

Having experimented further.. the issue seems to be in the style that wraps the div that is hidden.. In the following I show that the div is still in "transition". When I delete that style in the developer tools, I see my component.. That transition style starts with an opacity of 0. I wonder if this is my misuse of the Grow component, or is it an actual bug in material ui.

[image]

The following addition does not seem to clear the style

```
<Grow
            in={objectViewOpened}
            style={{ transformOrigin: "0 0 0" }}
            {...(objectViewOpened ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}
          >
            {object_controls_view}
          </Grow>
```

That comes right from their [documentation](https://mui.com/components/transitions/) (I dont fully understand that syntax):

[image]

Comment: Please provide your coding implementation

Comment: it would be better if you create a codesandbox to reproduce the issue

Comment: @KavinduVIndika I've added two sandbox links.. one with the icon .. it works.. the other with material-table.. it doesnt work.

Comment: @hgb123 I've added two sandbox links.. one with the icon .. it works.. the other with material-table.. it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

i think it might be z-index of map or the table try putting 100 but im not sure, and play with position relative aswell, and make sure table that has position: absolute has a parent with position: relative, body has position relative by default but sometimes you need to specify

Comment: I've added sandbox links.. I thought it was z-index as well.. but i fiddled with that to no avail. Please run the sandbox and see what you think

Comment: yea its not a z-index problem, im getting:  Failed prop type: The prop `onPageChange` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(TablePagination)`, but its value is `undefined` AND  The prop `onChangeRowsPerPage` of `ForwardRef(TablePagination)` is deprecated. Use the `onRowsPerPageChange` prop instead.

Comment: That comment is there by default.. I dont think its related to this problem.

Comment: I've isolated the problem to the transition style (starts with opacity 0). I've updated the stack description with a screenshot.

Comment: its weird, i have this Switch and it works on an old project, must be the leaflet or something else that causes the bug and not material-ui